# Invoke methods declared in protocol from the class implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, protocols

I've created a protocol named *RecDelegate* that's consisted of a method "*- (void) doSmtng*".
The protocol is defined in *rec.h* just before the rec interface declaration.
When I create a new application and adopt the *RecDelegate* to the new *appDelegate*, I can implement my own doSmtng, as needed to be.
What I don't understand is how can I invoke the doSmtng method from the rec.m (implementation of the class in which the protocol is defined...) - Meaning, how can I "Fire" the doSmtng in such a way that the new appDelegate's implementation will be triggered.

Hope what I said is relatively clear ... ;)

Thanks,
Guy.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you actually pasted your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two controllers below showing how to trigger an event from one to the other. 
Wherever there is a comment  "//HERE", it indicates there is delegation-related code.

**SENDER OF DELEGATE**

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 

@protocol SecondDelegate <NSObject> // HERE
  @optional
    -(void)MessageReceived:(NSString *)msg;
@end


@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    id<SecondDelegate> secondDelegate; // HERE
}

@property (assign) id<SecondDelegate> secondDelegate; // HERE

-(IBAction)trigger:(id)sender;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h" 

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize secondDelegate; // HERE

-(IBAction)trigger:(id)sender {
    if (self.secondDelegate != NULL && [self.secondDelegate  respondsToSelector:@selector(MessageReceived:)]) { // HERE
        [secondDelegate MessageReceived:@"my message"]; 
    }
}
```

**RECEIVER OF DELEGATE**

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h" // HERE

@interface FirstViewController : UINavigationController <SecondDelegate> // HERE

-(void)MessageReceived:(NSString*)msg; // HERE

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
        [self pushViewController:second animated:YES];
        second.secondDelegate = self; // HERE
        [second release];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)MessageReceived:(NSString *)msg { // HERE
    int y = 0; // HERE IT IS !
}
```

Comment: Great ! thanks a lot - it really helped. What I missed was the "second.secondDelegate = self;" section.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your `Rec` object that it should treat your `AppDelegate` as its delegate:

```
[rec setDelegate:appDelegate];
```

This could be done via Interface Builder or just after the `Rec` object is created.

Then, when the `Rec` object sends the delegate message to its delegate, the receiver will be your `AppDelegate` instance:

```
[[self delegate] doSmtng];
```

If the message the `Rec` object is sending to its delegate were an optional protocol message, it would instead be sent like this:

```
if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(optionalProtocolMethod)]) {
    [[self delegate] optionalProtocolMethod];
}
```

The `delegate` will usually be declared something like:

```
@property(assign, nonatomic) id<RecDelegate> delegate;
```

Because it is not retained, in `-dealloc`, the `Rec` object only needs to `nil` it out, not release it:

```
delegate = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeremy ! The problem in my case is that I don't necessarily knows who is appDelegate... I want my Rec object to be a blackbox that doesn't depend on external hardcoded app delegates.

Comment: Some code somewhere has to select an object to set as the other object's delegate. Something has to know that you want object A to be object B's delegate in order to connect the two. The code doesn't have to be in object B; you could just as easily have your app delegate set itself as the `Rec` object's delegate: `[rec setDelegate:self]`. As I said, this could also be done by your XIB (if `delegate` were an `IBOutlet`) or by whatever object creates the `Rec` object.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do something like that is using NSNotificationCenter

in your RecDelegate init method add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSmtng) name:@"someNotification" object:nil];
```

and in any another place / any class call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someNotification" object:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for answering ! I don't have any init method to RecDelegate as it's my protocol ...

Comment: Main idea was in calling some function from any place in your code. for example you're updating some data from many sources and from many classes, and it displayed in table. It will be easier just send "updateData" notification instead adding table controller as delegate to all classes.